# Applying substring operation to FOR token value (batch file)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, token

*(Edited question for clarity)*

Applying substring operation to a token value in a FOR does not work:

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%G in ("tokenvalue ") do (
    Echo %%G:~-1
)
```

The substring operation does not delete the space at the end. Instead, `:~-1` gets appended to the echoed result to produce:

> tokenvalue :~-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem here. Only when I append a space to the input file it also appears in the output file.

If you do

```
echo %%G >> D:\newfile.txt
```

then a space gets appended, obviously. This might be the case if you simplified your code before posting here.

If you indeed start out with a space in the input, then use the following:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%G in (D:\originalFile.txt) do (
    set "line=%%G"
    echo !line:~-1!>>D:\newfile.txt
)
```

You apply substring operations only to environment variables as the help already states.

In any case, if you're sure that the input file does not contain the trailing space, then you don't actually need the loop. A simple

```
type D:\originalFile.txt >> D:\newfile.txt
```

should suffice.

Comment: Yea I did simplify my code. Nice explanation. Really helped me out!

Comment: @BumbleBna: But you should be sure there are no `!` in your text file, else you will lose them

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Turns out I had a space in my code: '%%G>>D:\newfile.txt ' that was adding a space to the end of each output record... poop.